# Why do we consider that if initial & final positions are same then displacement of an object is Zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, distance, displacement

I was thinking on a basic high school problem about motion on one axis and came across one of those problem where displacement is zero because final and initial positions are same.
My question is that why do we have concept of displacement where we take the shortest path an object takes? it is cause of many problems like if the "displacement" is zero then work done will also be zero (even if there is some distance covered) and this will be irrespective of energy consumed .Why don't we just ditch the idea of a hypothetical shortest path and only consider distances.
One of reason i came across was that distance is scalar while velocity is vector
I think we can devise a system where we can define if distance is being taken as scalar or vector....(as in if distance is only in straight line then distance will be considered vector else scalar)
I know there is something stupid i am missing but motive of this post is to rediscover what that thing is....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(a) We are often interested in studying a body's motion throughout a period of time. Suppose that it followed a curved path. Then its displacements over successive time intervals would keep changing direction. So the body's velocity would keep changing direction, giving the body accelerations. That's one context in which we need the concept of displacement.

(b) You seem particularly interested in cases where a body performs a 'round trip' so its overall displacement is zero. You say that the work done on the body is zero. That's true for the work done on the body by a gravitational field, or, if the body has a charge, by an electric field due to static charges. I don't see why that's a problem, and I don't understand what you mean by "this will be irrespective of the energy consumed".

Note that not all forces on a body have this "conservative" property. If you push a book across a table, and then push it back to its starting point, you will have done a finite amount of work against friction – which always opposes the relative motion between surfaces.

Comment: "work done will be zero because displacement is zero" It depends: please see my third paragraph. What do you have in mind when you talk about energy being "consumed" to shift the object?

Comment: Your comment, to which I have just replied, seems to have disappeared. I assume that you've deleted it.

Comment: but in that book case result will be very much different we break the actions into components of a the book going from a to b (calculate the work done) and then from b to a

Comment: I am actually having problem in conveying my idea so i'll very soon link some explanation of my doubt here in the comment section..

Comment: Yes actually i have deleted that comment because  there was more to add to it and i accidentally posted that

Comment: We've all done that! Re your book-pushing comment: we do work pushing the book from a to b and then again from b to a. That's because the frictional force changes direction as the displacement changes direction. But you knew that! I await your promised explanation with interest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127442/discussion-between-sourav-singh-and-philip-wood).

Comment: Actually i had no idea about conservative and non-conservative forces hence the problem  ,it is going to be covered in my curriculum this year ,i saw a similar question here on stack exchange explaining between the two .Any ways Thanks for you cooperation!!

Comment: I hope your studies go well. You clearly strive for understanding – which not all students do!